How to use gcloud run deploy to specify a particular Dockerfile?
I have a directory that contains multiple Dockerfiles, such as api.Dockerfile and ui.Dockerfile. When using gcloud run deploy, I want to specify which Dockerfile should be used for building the container. Specifically, I want gcloud run deploy to take only api.Dockerfile.
Here’s the directory structure:
/project-directory
  ├── api.Dockerfile
  ├── ui.Dockerfile
  ├── src/
  └── other-files/

Is there an option with gcloud run deploy to specify a particular Dockerfile (e.g., api.Dockerfile) instead of the default Dockerfile?

gcloud command do 2 things: Run a Cloud Build to build your container, then deploy the container on Cloud Run. It's a generic process and you have to comply with the default parameters (and names). If you want something more custom, create your containers with Cloud Build then deploy them on Cloud Run.

No, gcloud run deploy doesn't have an option to directly specify the docker image file name. But you can achieve this using a two-step process:

Build the docker image using the docker build command, pass the dockerfile location and assign a
name to the image.
Use the gcloud run deploy command with the
--container option, specifying the name you assigned to the image in step 1.

Here's an example:
docker build -t myimage -f api.Dockerfile .

gcloud run deploy --container=myimage

